# How do you display product in colorbox lightbox in magento 1.9 custom theme

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-attribute, product-view

I have successfully managed to get the colorbox pop up window to display on page. However beyond that I am not getting much success in displaying the product - At best I get the entire webpage loading in the box :(

I've created a version of media.phtml within my theme directory:

Package>Theme>Template>Catalog>>product>View>media.phtml

All my modifications have been done in this file which basically consist of

- Removing the zoom script
- Adding the colorbox calls

It looks like I'm missing the specific syntax or format that is required to have the product display, I really don't want to use an extension to achieve this and would be grateful for a little direction.

There is a mass of info for achieving this on older versions but I've struggled to locate this for mage 1.9+

Any assistance or guidance would be grand.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of guess in the dark as you don't link to exactly the issue you are having.  However, with the knowledge and understanding of how these popup windows I have used in the past work, I am guessing that the url/trigger that should contain your image url instead contains the url for the page you are on.  This would explain why the entire page loads in the popup box and not just an image.

If this doesn't help, please provide more information on what the current behavior is, including links if possible.